# Android Studio: Unable to build app due to gradle distribution url error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know this question has been asked before but I haven't been able to fix the issue. I am running Android Studio version 3.1.4. I am trying to run an app that I cloned from a Github repository. But even before I try to run it, I get this error:

> my-app: sync failed
>
> Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.4-20171031235950+0000-all.zip

How do I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check and change the distribution url in the properties file  `$rootDir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. See property `distributionUrl`.

Value should be something as follows (update the gradle version depending on your Android Studio version)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar error when I tried importing the Sunshine project from the Udacity Android development course. I fixed the issue by downloading the mentioned zip file and extracted it to the `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\native` folder.

[image: Directory]

Then in Gradle settings, use `local Gradle distribution` and set the `Gradle home` path to the downloaded gradle folder.

[image: Gradle settings]

[Check this video for more information](https://youtu.be/I-Kjrmt0pp0)

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the Gradle version from the gradle-wrapper.properties file
2. Download the Gradle bin file from internet, then extract it.
3. File menu-->Settings-->Build & Tools-->Gradle-->Use Gradle from: From
   drop down select a specified location and browse to the location
   where you have saved the Gradle bin zip file. (Default settings is use from ;gradle-wrapper.properties' file)
   4.File menu-->Invalidate caches and re-run

[Gradle properties file]

[image]

[Gradle settings]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by the following steps: (currently using Android 3.6.3)

This worked for me.

- Exit android studio then make the below changes.
- Go to `C:\Users\UserName.android` and rename the `build-cache` folder to `build-cache.bak`.
- Go to `C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.6\system` and rename these folders:

  - `caches` to `caches.bak`
  - `compiler` to `compiler.bak`
  - `compile-server` to `compile-server.bak`
  - `conversion` to `conversion.bak`
  - `external_build_system` to `external_build_system.bak`
  - `frameworks` to `frameworks.bak`
  - `gradle` to `gradle.bak`
  - `resource_folder_cache` to `resource_folder_cache.bak`
- Open the Android Studio and open your project again.

If the folder is not in the Android3.6 folder, move to the next step.